# Ionic ng-change not fired at first time when selecting toggle button to unselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

Iam trying to get value of toggle but its not working when first unchecked toggle button hit after checked it works fine.

```
<ul class="list  has-header">
  <li class="item item-toggle" ng-repeat="ingr in ingredients|filter:searching">
    {{ingr.INGREDIENTNAME}}
    <label class="toggle toggle-energized" >
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ingr.INGREDIENTSTATUS" ng-change='changeingrStatus(ingr.INGREDIENTCODE,ingr.INGREDIENTSTATUS)' ng-checked="{{ingr.INGREDIENTSTATUS==1?true:false}}">
      <div class="track">
        <div class="handle"></div>
      </div>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Controller.js

```
$scope.changeingrStatus = function(code, status) {
  console.log(status);
}
```

Comment: You can try to use $scope.$watch to catch update in the checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `ng-model` attribute along with `ng-checked`. I would suggest to use `ng-model` only.

Read [ngChecked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) page for details:

> Note that this directive should not be used together with `ngModel`, as this can lead to unexpected behavior.